# How to Stop GIF in iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I integrate one **GIF** file in `UIImageview`. and it works fine for me , but it will runs infinite time.I want to stop the gif at specific time or Cycle of **GIF**?

Comment: did you use library for gif ?

Comment: @KKRocks, yes I used SwiftGif third party library

Comment: Add your code, how you are setting GIF into UIImageView?

Comment: @Venkat           let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "animation", withExtension: "gif")!)
        self.imgViewGIF.image = UIImage.gif(data: imageData)

Comment: see this link : https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif/wiki/Extended-use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to configure your imageview as mentioned here

https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif/wiki/Extended-use

```
let jeremyGif = UIImage.gifWithName("jeremy")

let imageView = UIImageView(...)
// Uncomment the next line to prevent stretching the image
// imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
// Uncomment the next line to set a gray color.
// You can also set a default image which get's displayed 
// after the animation
// imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

// Set the images from the UIImage
imageView.animationImages = jeremyGif?.images
// Set the duration of the UIImage
imageView.animationDuration = jeremyGif!.duration
// Set the repetitioncount
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
// Start the animation
imageView.startAnimating()
```